# code for starting an application on receiving SMS from particular number in android

Tags: android

hi there i want to start an application on receiving sms from a particular number or particular port. i am trying it with onReceiveintent but i m struggling. so, anyone there to help me in detail?Please explain me with code.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...it will start camera when you received sms from the port 5556

```
 public class MySmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        private String yourNumber = "5556";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Log.v("MySMS", intent.getAction());
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                if (messages.length > -1) {
                    String no = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    Log.v("MySMS", no);
                    if (no != null && no.trim().equals(yourNumber)) {
                        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        resultIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                "com.android.camera",
                                "com.android.camera.Camera"));
                        ResolveInfo ri = manager.resolveActivity(resultIntent,
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        if (ri != null) {
                            context.startActivity(resultIntent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for quick responce i tried but camera is not started can u provide me "com.android.camera.Camera" package with camera class. Which i think it is user defined package so plese provide me the details of that Camera class and also i am receiving a toast message and my application is force closing

Comment: Hi my application is force closing when i receive any sms from port 5556 can you please help me out of this situation its very urgent.Thanks in advance

Comment: hi ramtej...i think you are getting force close dialog in emulator for camera application...this is emulator problem...don't worry...you can start your application by passing your package name and activity name in resultIntent.componentName(new ComponentName(
                                "your package name",
                                "your activity with the package"))
function

Comment: for example your package name is com.app.test and your activity is MyActivity...........then you can call that method like this resultIntent.componentName(new ComponentName( "com.app.test", "com.app.test.MyActivity"))